# Restrict Mercurial repository access

Tags: mercurial, ssh, dvcs, mercurial-server

I have a Mercurial server using [mercurial-server](http://www.lshift.net/mercurial-server.html). I edited `access.conf` in `hgadmin` repo as follows:

```
deny repo=a/b
read user=x/**
read user=y/**

write repo=a/b user=x/abc
write repo=a/b user=y/z
```

But user `z` still can't access this repo. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation mentions](http://dev.lshift.net/paul/mercurial-server/docbook.html#id3886331):

> `user=globpattern`: path to the user's key

So the path of z's key might be wrong, or the path of the repo is off.

> When considering a request, mercurial-server steps through all the rules in `/etc/mercurial-server/access.conf` and then all the rules in `access.conf` in `hgadmin`, looking for a rule which matches on every condition.
>   **The first match determines whether the request will be allowed**; if there is no match in either file, the request will be denied.

Other possibility: Maybe a deny rule (applicable for user `z`) is found first.

Answer (score 2):

The first matching rule applies.  In this instance the deny rule is first, so it will match first; no user will be given access to repo a/b no matter what other rules follow this one.

Try placing the two write rules above the deny rule.

Note also that any rules in /etc/mercurial-server/access.conf will logically precede these rules.

Comment: yeah you are totally right , both /etc/mercurial-server/access.conf and access.conf of hgadmin repo contains conflicting rules that lead to this mess , but i'm facing now a new weird problem 
i have roles as following:
"read repo=a/b user=users/x
deny repo=a/b"
==> this lead to user x can't clone this repo

another roles :
"read repo=a/b  user=users/*
deny repo=a/b"
==> this lead to user x can clone repo a/b  
any ideas why this happens

Answer (score 1):

There is one more especiality about mercurial server that you may need to know. That you can not duplicate keys several times in keys/ of hgadmin. Because on server side those keys are compiled into /var/lib/mercurial-server/.ssh/authorized_keys. So if you specify same key in different key files in keys/ then when hg do ssh it will use first occurence of the key in authorixed_keys and probbaly refer to first only repo and disable access to another repos which refer to another file (but with same key)